# GCC's two unusual error messages

Tags: c++, gcc, diagnostics

Today, I came across two error messages which I never seen before. It's completely new to me.

Here is the code:

```
template<typename T>
struct adder { adder(const T &item) { } };

template<typename T>
void initializer(const T &item) {  adder<T>(item); }

int main() 
{
   initializer("const string literal");
}
```

On compiling, GCC gives these errors:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘void initializer(const T&)’:
>   **prog.cpp:6: error: declaration of ‘adder<T> item’ shadows a parameter**
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘void initializer(const T&) [with T = char [21]]’:
>   prog.cpp:10:   instantiated from here
>   **prog.cpp:6: error: declaration of ‘adder<char [21]> item’ shadows a parameter**
>   **prog.cpp:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘adder<char [21]>::adder()’**
>   prog.cpp:3: note: candidates are: adder<T>::adder(const T&) [with T = char [21]]
>   prog.cpp:3: note:                 adder<char [21]>::adder(const adder<char [21]>&)

---

See the bold text. One error is shown **twice**, which is this

> error: declaration of ‘**adder<T> item**’ shadows a parameter
>   error: declaration of **‘adder<char [21]> item**’ shadows a parameter

What does it mean? Why does it show *twice* with different template arguments? First one with `T`, second one with `char [21]`?

EDIT: does `adder<T>(item)` declare variable with name *item*? But that is not what I intended. I think it should create a temporary object passing *item* as argument to the constructor.

**I would like to know the section from the Standard which deals with this issue!**

---

Other interesting error is this:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘adder<char [21]>::adder()’

Which indicates that the compiler is looking for **default constructor**? But I'm wondering why is the compiler looking for it when in fact my code doesn't use it **at line 6**?

---

Code at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/jrdLL

Comment: `adder<T>(item)` means `adder<T> item;` - And then the two errors make sense.

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding what is happening is to realize that:
    adder(item);
is a definition of a local variable named item and having type
adder; the parentheses are superfluous, but perfectly
permissable.  If you want to call the constructor, you'll have
to disambiguate, by writing it in some way that cannot be
interpreted as a data definition, say:
    adder((item));
(I'm not sure what use this may be.  It constructs a temporary
object of adder, then destructs it at the end of the
expression.)

The actual error messages should be clear(er) once the statement
is understood as a data declaration: function parameters are
treated as if they were defined in the top level block of the
function, so adder(item) is a duplicate (and contradictory)
definition, and adder doesn't have a default constructor, so
you can't define an instance of it without providing arguments.

Comment: Re the fact that one error appears twice: the compiler parses
a template definition twice (or more).  Once when it first sees
it, and then each time it instantiates the template.  Not all
errors can be detected during the first parse: the compiler has
no way of knowing that adder<T> doesn't have a default
constructor until it knows T.  But it can clearly see that
adder<T> item defines a variable with the same name as the
parameter, regardless of T, so it issues an error when it parses
the template, and then again when it tries to instantiate it.

Comment: This is good. But I would like to know the section from the Standard according to which `adder<T>(item)` is declaration of a variable with name *item*.

Comment: §6.8/1.  Basically, if a sequence of tokens can be interpreted
as a declaration or an expression-statement, it is
a declaration.  Naturally, you wouldn't normally use the
parentheses if you wanted to just declare an adder<T>.  But
they're legal (and necessary to construct more complex types).
So it's a declaration.

Answer (score 4):

> Which indicates that the compiler is looking for default constructor? But I'm wondering why is the compiler looking for it when in fact my code doesn't use it at line 6?

Because compiler think that you declare local variable with name item.

http://codepad.org/YBPKCvmm

Answer (score 3):

I only have access to the C++0x draft at the moment, so I can't give you the current chapter and verse, but I don't think much has changed.
In 0x it's in section 6.8 - Ambiguity Resolution:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar
>   involving expression-statements and
>   declarations: An expression-statement
>   with a function-style explicit type
>   conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost
>   subexpression can be indistinguishable
>   from a declaration where the first
>   declarator starts with a (. In those
>   cases the statement is a declaration.

[...]

```
T(a); // declaration
```

That is, a declaration of a variable named "a" of type T.

If your `adder<T>(item)` were to define a temporary (un-named) object, it would be an expression-statement, but if something can be parsed as either a declaration-statement or an expression-statement, C++ parses it as a declaration-statement.

> [...] the resolution is to consider any
>   construct that could possibly be a
>   declaration a declaration.
>   (8.2)

In other words, it's a cousin to everyone's dear old friend, the Most Vexing Parse.

*Update:*
I looked at ambiguity resolution in C++03, and those passages are identical.

Answer (score 1):

"shadowing" means that two objects have the same name, which the language allows at this point, but might not be intended.

Comment: That's wrong.  §3.3.2 of the standard: "A parameter name shall
not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function
definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated
with a function-try-block."

Comment: I, too, would prefer if compilers implemented the standard. :)